# Use sessions to create a disclaimer and agreement page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a page with a Disclaimer and Agreement in WordPress/PHP.

**Disclaimer:**

1. If users select 'UK' from a dropdown, they are sent to an Agreement page.
2. If users select any other country, they are sent to an 'Access Denied' page.

**Agreement:**

1. If the user clicks "I agree" they are sent to the final stage "Well Done".
2. If the user clicks "Disagree" they are sent to the 'Access Denied' page.

I've come up with the following, but the select options are not working and I'm not sure how to direct all countries except the UK to an access denied page.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php 

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['grant_access'])) {
        $_SESSION['grant_access'] = ‘unset’;
}

if(isset($_POST['United Kingdom'])) {
        $_SESSION['grant_access'] = ‘partialset’;
}

if($_SESSION['grant_access'] == ‘partialset’) { ?>
 '<p>You are nearly there. Now you must agree.</p>';
    <form method="post">
        <form method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="I Agree" name="agree" />
        </form>
<?php 
}

if($_SESSION['grant_access'] == ‘unset’) {
?>
        <h1>Disclaimer.</h1>
        <p>Choose your country.</p>

        <form method="submit">
          <select>
            <option value="Australia" title="Australia">Australia</option>
            <option value="France" title="France">France</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom" title="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="United States" title="United States">United States</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

<?php
} else {

echo 'Well done.';

} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `name="..."` on your select, so nothing will be submitted there. The `value` of the selected option is what's submited, so you'd need:

```
<select name="country">
   <option value="United Kingdom" />UK
   ...
</select>
```

and

```
if(isset($_POST['country']) && ($_POST['country'] == 'United Kingdom')) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you've got a typo in your `if statement`. You're missing the closing `]`. It should be `if(isset($_POST['country']) && $_POST['country'] == 'United Kingdom')`

Comment: Thanks, I have added this, but when I click submit with UK selected, it doesn't go  to 'partialset', it just reloads the form. Any ideas?

Comment: @user: `method="submit"` is not a valid method either. e.g. your html is fundamentally broken.

Comment: @user18577, you should also set `action` ( you can place it next to `method` ). If you want to post data back to this same page, for instance, you could have `action = ""` or `action = "path-to-file/file.php"`.

Comment: @user18577, it would help if you would define what **not working** means. :)